# homework: never ending loop 5**200000

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, python-3.x

I had an homework assignment: to find the maximal sum of 50,000 consecutive digits in the number 5**200,000. 
I know that if i make a for loop over this number it will not end in a feasible time. 
I tried to put this number in a list and iterate over the list, and I don't understand how does it work that way? why doesn't it act like in the first case? what makes it faster?
that's my code:

```
def maxdigits(number,digits):
    s=str(number) #conversting the number to a string
    l = [int(char) for char in s]
    maximum = current = sum(l[:digits])
    for i in range(0,len(l)-digits):
        current = current-l[i]+l[i+digits]
        if current > maximum: maximum = current
    return maximum
```

Comment: Define "the maximal sum of 50,000 consecutive digits in the number 5**200,000". How is this different from the sum of the digits? Are you talking about any 50,000 consecutive digits? In any case, your problem here is about mathematical insight, rather than code.

Comment: yes i converted 5**200000 to a string

Comment: The code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Are you doing a [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. I think I understand the assignment and your code looks like it's probably either correct or very close. What are you saying this is faster than? Can you provide the code that you are saying is slower, because your description of it isn't clear enough for me.

Comment: it runs fine that wasnt my question..

Comment: why if i make a for loop on the number 5**200000 it stuck but this code doesnt?

Comment: What does that mean? A number isn't iterable, so I don't understand what a for loop on a number means. Do you mean `for i in range(5**200000)`?

Comment: That's because instead of going from 0 ... 5**200000, you are going from 0 ... 139 795 - 50000. 139 795 is the number of digits in that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking why does a loop over the digits of the number `5**200000` complete quickly, while looping over all the numbers in the range `0` to `(5**200000)-1` inclusive take a long time.

I think the only reason this isn't obvious to you is because these are large numbers that are difficult to write down. Think about it again. Would it be faster to loop over the seven digits of `1000000`, or over the million numbers from `0` to `999999`? There are `139795` digits in `5**200000`. It's not a huge amount of work to do a simple loop `139795` times. It is a gargantuan amount of work to do a simple loop `5**200000` times. That's a ridiculous number. If every atom in the universe were a computer and each ran for the lifetime of the universe I doubt they would succeed in doing anything `5**200000` times.

Answer (score 1):

The code runs faster because instead of iterating over the list

```
[ 0, 1, ..., 5 ** 200000 ]
```

you are iterating over

```
[ 0, 1, ..., 139 795 - 50000 ]
```

which is orders of magnitude smaller than the first list.

And the way you calculate the number of digits in that number is:

```
200000 * log5 + 1
```